# Pricing a piece of asset whose dividend stream following a Markovian matrix

Tags: asset-pricing, markov

I'm trying to calculate the result of an simple example on page 326-327, in [Harrison and Kreps(1978)](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~lpederse/courses/LAP/papers/ShortSales/HarrisonKreps78.pdf). It's pricing a piece of asset whose dividend stream is a simple Markovian process.

[image]

[image]

Here's my attempt to replicate investor $1$'s evaluation of this asset.

$p^1(0) = 0 + \frac{3}{4} ( \frac{1}{2} p^{1}(0)  + \frac{1}{2} p^{1}(1) )$

$p^1(1) = 1+  \frac{3}{4} ( \frac{2}{3} p^{1}(0) + \frac{1}{3} p^{1}(1) )$

But when I substitute the numerical value given in the bottom of second screenshot, they don't match. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your equations are for cum-dividend prices, i.e. the price plus dividend today. The paper refers to ex-dividend prices. The correct two equations for investor group $a=1$ are
\begin{align}
p^1(0) =&\ \frac{3}{4} \left(\frac{1}{2}p^1(0) + \frac{1}{2}(1+p^1(1))\right) \\
p^1(1) =&\ \frac{3}{4} \left(\frac{2}{3}p^1(0) + \frac{1}{3}(1+p^1(1))\right)
\end{align}
When you solve these two equations for $p^1(0)$ and $p^1(1)$ you get the correct results.